# How do I easily select inputs on which I can actually write something

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I do something like the following in a short way?

```
$('input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=password], textarea')
```

Something like `$(':canTypeIn')` would be nice.

I want to select all the inputs or textarea that accept inputing chars, example of **NOT** returned inputs:

- `input[type=checkbox]`
- `input[type=radio]`
- `input[type=hidden]`
- `input[type=color]`

And so on.

Example of returned inputs

- `input[type=text]`
- `textarea`
- `input[type=number]`
- `[contenteditable]`
- `input[type=password]`

And so on

What I'm searching for is a way to select all those inputs without having to type each one by one.

Comment: What about a readonly input field? Or an element with [`contenteditable="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)? Should this select that?

Comment: You can just do `$('input, textarea')`

Comment: `$('input, textarea')` ?

Comment: dont want to select `input[type=checkbox]` or `input[type=radio]`

Comment: You could also just exclude `input` types that don't allow input, like `submit` and `img`

Comment: @ntgCleaner / Carl That would also select inputs with `type="hidden"`.

Comment: You have `input[type=number]` listed twice.  Is one supposed to be `input[type=password]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom selectors with jQuery which means you need to put some work in to maintain it if and when new input types are created (as they undoubtedly will be, in the future), but this will make your job much easier as you'll only have the one piece of code to maintain.  I believe this code will cover all types of element that you can currently type in, but it's quite clear so making any changes to it should be fairly simple...

```
$.expr[':'].canTypeIn = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {

    // immediately return false if the element is not visible or is read only
    if (obj.style.visibility === "hidden" || obj.style.display === "none" || obj.readOnly === true || obj.disabled === true) {
        return false;
    }

    // an array of input types that we know we can type in
    var types = [
        "date",
        "datetime",
        "datetime-local",
        "email",
        "month",
        "number",
        "password",
        "search",
        "tel",
        "text",
        "time",
        "url",
        "week"
    ];

    // if the element is an input then check what type of input it is
    if (obj.tagName === "INPUT") {
        return types.indexOf(obj.type) !== -1;
    }

    if (obj.tagName === "TEXTAREA") {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

**Usage**

```
$(":canTypeIn");
```

Here's a working jsfiddle example...

**http://jsfiddle.net/Kz6w3/17/**

Open the console to see a list of the 4 elements that you can type in.

(thanks to gfrobenius for starting that - I pinched the html as an example!)

Comment: Perfect, just the disabled are also selected but that's an easy edit, thanks.

Comment: Yep - sorry I missed that.  You're right that it's an easy edit, but for completeness here I've updated the code and the example link.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE VERSION 3:**  I noticed you don't want hidden items either.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Kz6w3/8/**

```
disabled <input id="one" type="text" disabled="true" value="test"><br>
readonly <input id="two" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="test"><br>
editable <input id="three" type="text" value="test"><br>
editable but invisible <input id="four" type="text" value="test" style="display:none;"><br>
button <input id="five" type="button" value="test"><br><br><br>

disabled <textarea id="six" disabled="true"></textarea><br>
readonly <textarea id="seven"readonly="readonly"></textarea><br>
editable <textarea id="eight"></textarea><br>
editable but invisible <textarea id="nine" style="display:none;"></textarea><br>

//just keep applying ":visible:enabled:not([readonly])" to your
//different types like you have listed in the original question.
//This works, might be a little lengthy
 $('input[type=text]:visible:enabled:not([readonly]),textarea:visible:enabled:not([readonly])').each(function() {
     alert(this.id+' is editable');
});
```

**ANOTHER IDEA**

I don't know how to make the selectors shorter.  So it'd actually be less text to create an `EDITABLE` function, something like this...

**http://jsfiddle.net/Kz6w3/13/**

```
window.editable=function(obj){
    if(obj.disabled) return false;
    if($(obj).is('[readonly]')) return false;
    if(obj.style.display === 'none') return false;
    return true;
}

$('input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=password], textarea').each(function() {
    alert(this.id+' is editable: '+editable(this));
});
```

Comment: Cannot change the DOM or I would have add classes.

Comment: I don't follow.  I'm not saying you have to add classes.  Those fields are for demonstration only.  You only need to use the jQuery line to find out what inputs are editable. (add textarea if you need to)  Make sense?

Comment: This will return all inputs that are enabled and not readonly.  This will include inputs that do not accept text entry.

Comment: @Archer What are you talking about.  That's what he's asking for.  Only editable ones.  Actually he also asked for it to not return invisible fields so he is an even better answer: **http://jsfiddle.net/Kz6w3/1/**

Comment: Calm down - being wrong is no reason to be rude.  The title is, "How do I easily select inputs on which I can actually write something?"  Your code will return inputs of all types, including submit buttons.  Please explain how you can enter text in a submit button.

Comment: oh yeah, see my demo fields, sorry, s/he was specifically asking about the visible/readonly/disable selectors.

Comment: Here it is with more items added to it: **http://jsfiddle.net/Kz6w3/8/**  I was assuming s/he knew that part as they demonstrated the different types in the question already.  Just apply the `visible:enabled:not([readonly])` to each.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Guys my bad I think I'm not clear enough, what I want is to select all the inputs that accept chars input, like a `input[type=checkbox]` would not be return but something like `input[type=text]` would be returned

Comment: It's in the answer: `$('input[type=text]:visible:enabled:not([readonly]),textarea:visible:enabled:not([readonly])')` just add the `number` if that is something you want to include also, like: `$('input[type=text]:visible:enabled:not([readonly]),input[type=number]:visible:enabled:not([readonly]),textarea:visible:enabled:not([readonly])')`  Hope we're on same page now. :)

Comment: I dont want to select the one that are visible or enabled or not readonly, I want to select them all without having to write each type, something like `$(':canTypeIn')` instead of `$('input[type=text], input[type=number]...')` I think @Archer get what I mean.

Comment: I get it now.  Your initial post said "that accept text only and that are visible." that's why I added :visible, so you would NOT select invisible ones (if there were some on your page).  I see you updated the question.  Sorry, I do not know of anything like `$(':canTypeIn')`.  I'd just list them out, it's just a small handful.

Comment: This answer is also great but solution 1 does not work with the other input types

Answer (score -1):

so this might be cheesy but it's a thought.

in your css set display value based on ID for each element

then set an ID for each input.

set a global variable of inputs or ID's & use it when you need it:

```
var textFields = 'input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=password], textarea';
$(textFields).each(function(index){
  if($($(this).attr('id')).css('display') != 'none'){
    //do something
  }
});
```